# Ng new installing an angular 8 project instead of 9

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I ran ng new  and I got this error `E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http:**********/repository/npm-all/@babel%2fpreset-env - Not found`
I checked the angular version and it turns out its angular 8 and not 9.  And I see these errors:

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            8.3.23
@angular-devkit/schematics      8.3.23
@angular/cli                    8.3.23
@schematics/angular             8.3.23
@schematics/update              0.803.23
rxjs                            <error>
typescript                      <error>
```

I've tried running `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular`, `npm i @angular/cli`, `npm update`, `ng-update` etc. Does anyone know a solution to this>

**UPDATE** - Fixed by correcting the link in my .npmrc file. However Angular 8 is still being installed instead of 9

Comment: Install the latest (global) cli version with `npm i -g @angular/cli@latest`. Then your `ng new` will install with the latest correct dependencies

Comment: have you tried installing it as a dev dependency?  `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`.  Try @poul's comment as well

Comment: Yeah I tried all of that I figured out that the issue was it was pointing to the wrong link. but it still installs angular 8 instead of 9 @PoulKruijt